# Flash content dosen't load only if I refresh the page

Tags: html, flash

I have a site with a small flash content. The flash content doesn't load when the page loads, only if I refresh the site manually. It does it on more browsers so it's not about compatibility, and when I refresh the site it works so the embeding is fine too.
When I close the browser and open it again the problem starts again.
Could somebody help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us a link/code/something?

Comment: Works for me. I tested it on Mac and Windows XP.

Comment: try with opera. Clean all private data and after that open the site. The flash doesn't appear only if you refresh it. (it does so for me). It has also problem with IE and safari too.

Answer (score 0):

In Opera I got (once) the error message (from Flash player): some xml file was missing (can't reproduce this error anymore).

Is this xml file created 'on the fly'? 
Check the server if it always serve the file properly.

Comment: Could you tell me how to display error messages from flash? Otherwise, if you clear the private data in opera and open the site again, you should see the problem. Thank you

Comment: In order to see the error messages you need to install the Flash Player in debug version. I tried Opera, cleared private data, but it worked for me all the time (failed just once).